# Android Content Uri Format

Tags: android

I have been retrieving images from `MediaStore` in the following way...

```
Uri uriExternal = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = {
     MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
     MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED
};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
    .query(uriExternal, projection,
           MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " IS NOT NULL",
           null,
           MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

if(cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

         paths.add(uriExternal.toString() + "/" + _id);
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Basically, I'm simply appending the file id to the external content provider uri. This makes a uri that I can use with content providers...

```
content://media/external/images/media/{id}
```

It all works perfectly fine, all external images are displayed and loaded flawlessly. However, since I've failed to find proper documentation, I'm a little concerned I'm not doing things the proper way. Especially because of the way I'm constructing the uri...kind of hard-coding it...

The questions are...

#### Is this the correct way to construct a content uri for an external image?

#### Is there a more reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: see `android.content.ContentUris` documentation

Comment: As pskink hints at, there is [`ContentUris.withAppendedId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html#withAppendedId(android.net.Uri,%20long)). For `MediaStore`, this works well. It's not a universal thing, though, across all providers.

Comment: thanks guys. Can any of you answer it so I can accept it? @CommonsWare, love your books, keep them coming!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I [use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html#withAppendedId(android.net.Uri,%20long)). That way, I don't have to worry about whether I am starting with a `Uri` that ends in `/` or not. :-)

In general, `MediaStore` adheres to the original `ContentProvider` vision of using the content ID as the last path segment of a `Uri` pointing to the content. However, that is *not* a general rule, and it will not work for all providers.